# How do I prove that $I+T^*T$ is invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T$ be a bounded linear operator in a Hilbert space, $T^*$ the adjoint of $T$. 
Then how to show that $I + T^*T$ is invertible?

Thanks.

Comment: We should be able to prove that $A - I$ is a positive operator implies that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: My thought is: Assume (I + T*T) to be not invertible, then there exists some x not equals to 0 and (I + T*T)x = 0. Then <(I + T*T)x, x> = 0 can lead to <x,x>+<Tx,Tx>=0, which is a contradiction. But I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: In infinite dimensional spaces, we can have linear operators that have a trivial kernel but fail to be invertible.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A=I+T^{\star}T$. Then $A=A^{\star}$ and
$$
           \|x\|^{2}\le \|x\|^{2}+\|Tx\|^{2}=(Ax,x) \le \|Ax\|\|x\| \\
                   \implies \|x\| \le \|Ax\|.
$$
So $A$ is injective.

The range of $A$ is dense because $\mathcal{R}(A)^{\perp}=\mathcal{N}(A^{\star}) = \mathcal{N}(A)=\{0\}$. To see that the range is closed, suppose $\{ Ax_n \}$ converges to some $y$. Then $\{ Ax_n \}$ is a Cauchy sequence; hence $\{ x_n \}$ is a Cauchy sequence because
$$
                      \|Ax_n - Ax_m \| \ge \|x_n-x_m\|.
$$
Therefore $\{ x_n \}$ converges to some $x$ and $\{ Ax_n \}$ converges to $Ax$, which gives $Ax=y$. So the range of $A$ is closed, which proves that $A$ is surjective.

So $A$ is a linear bijection, and $\|x\|\le \|Ax\|$ implies $\|A^{-1}y\|\le \|y\|$. Hence $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Could you please also prove that it's bounded?

Comment: @Teodorism : The last line of the post from Sept 29, 2015 shows that $A^{-1}$ is bounded. $A$ itself is bounded because $T$, $T^*$ are bounded. What is missing for you?